# Can I include review scores in CV?

Tags: cv, rejection

I have submitted a manuscript to a CS conference, and it was rejected but with decent scores given by the reviewers (just under the accept treshold). If I list the manuscript as a preprint in my CV, is it OK to mention that I submitted to that conference and it got rejected with those scores? This version of the CV would not be publicly accessible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is OK and what is wise may not be the same thing. I doubt that this would be wise. Instead, I'd list it as "in preparation" if you intend to revise and submit elsewhere. Showing work in progress is a good thing and forward looking. Being rejected is less of a good thing, and also backward looking.

Comment: Do you think mentioning rejection with "weak accept" reviews from a good conference would always be a negative? My situation is that I have no publications in the area of the conference (theoretical CS) and I'm planning on applying for phd positions in it.

Comment: Certainly more negative than positive.

Comment: I agree. "In Prep" is the way to go, but be clear on what it is in prep for. "In preparation, to be submitted to X CONFERENCE, YEAR". Listing an "almost, but rejected" on your CV gives you nothing. Listing the possibility of a good acceptance shows what your are actively working on and that you are familiar with the field. You aren't even a PhD student yet, you aren't expected to have many, or even any, publications.

Answer (score 4):

Scores alone without the associated reviews have only little informative value, since the final decision usually does not depend on a threshold, but on a discussion between PC members. Maybe the reviewers who gave a positive score were "informed outsiders", whereas the most expert reviewer saw a major flaw and fought against the paper's acceptance? From just looking at the scores, we can't know. Therefore, I would be skeptical if I was reading your CV and saw this entry.

Answer (score 1):

You should not.  CVs are for factual information.  Review scores are opinions, not facts.